# magento configurable product have no “Add to cart” button

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have created a configurable product and also added two products in it with proper size and color option but in the frontend in product details page, there is no add to cart button or select size/color option.I also added quantity and selected in stock option for both of the products.Here is my screenshot.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: have you clear cache or refresh?

Comment: yes. but one thing is that, in the backend configurable product's quantity is showing zero whereas, the two simple product added to configurable product has the quantity respectively 2,4. How to increase the quantity of configurable product as there is no option to increase quantity in inventory.

Comment: configurable product depend only associated product so it display proper.can u tell exact what have you done so far?

Comment: Looking at the Screen Capture i don't even see the option selections. So i would say you have some broken code in configurable.phtml or view.phtml files.

Comment: Is this problem got solved for you? If yes, can u post me the answer and steps that u followed. Me too facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Also set In Stock for configurable product also and do reindexing.

Comment: i already did that.....but no of quantity of configurable product is showing zero and there is no option to increase quantity..

Answer (score 0):

Configurable product needs to be set to in stock, Enabled, and have Associated Products
Simple Products need to have QTY, in stock, Enabled, and associated with a Parent (can only do that on the parent).

After those are set, you will need to clear cache and reindex.